# Mapping optional query params in WSO2 ESB API resource

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have to mapping query params to send request to endpoint in API resource in WSO2 ESB.

Those query params are optional. For example, the following are examples of calls to resource:

```
http://server:port/service?q1={q1}
http://server:port/service?q2={q2}&q3={q3}
```

I need to have a single resource to do this.

How can I do this?

Basically, I have to read query params in request and put it in the call to endpoint uri.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have dynamic URIs using ***url-mapping*** attribute.

Here is an example:

```xml
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test_api" context="/testService">
   <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/*">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="paramQ1" expression="$ctx:query.param.q1"></property>
            <property name="paramQ2" expression="$ctx:query.param.q2"></property>
            <property name="paramQ3" expression="$ctx:query.param.q3"></property>
         </log>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9766/services/"></address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send></send>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

To validate the presence of those query params its possible to use [Filter Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Filter+Mediator). A good example of it can be found [here](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/12/restful-integration-with-wso2-esb/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've defined my resource like above. But, it doesn't work, tomcat doens't recived anything.

Comment: If you are calling this url, **http to http://esb:port/testService?q1=XXX** will not work. The correct is: _http://esb:port/testService/?q1=XXX_ or _http://esb:port/testService/test?q1=XXX_